# Angular DatePicker - Multiple directives > [datepicker, datepicker]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm trying to use the 720Kb datepicker.
https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker

While using the simple example :

```
<datepicker>
  <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
</datepicker>
```

I'm getting the blow error:

> angular.js:11655 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives
>   [datepicker, datepicker] asking for new/isolated scope on: 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=datep…epicker%20class%3D%22datepicker%22%20date-format%3D%22dd%2FMM%2Fyyyy%22%3E
>       at angular.js:63

I noticed that if I'm changing the name of the directive in the src file for example to  datepickercust the above example will work (with changing the tags).

```
<datepickercust >
  <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
</datepickercust>
```

Also , if I'm trying the same example by changing the 'datepicker' tags to 'div' tags , and adding class='datepicker' it works fine.

```
  <div class="datepicker">
      <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
  </div>
```

I just can't understand what's going on here... why the original example not working ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have multiple datepicker directives in your app. Check where is the other one and remove it.

Comment: You can view a slightly more detailed error message here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=datep%E2%80%A6epicker%20class%3D%22datepicker%22%20date-format%3D%22dd%2FMM%2Fyyyy%22%3E%20at%20angular.js:63

Comment: That's really strange , I removed the 720 date picker but not removed the html code and looks like there is datepicker directive in angular.js . I can see the below warning : "datepicker is now deprecated. Use uib-datepicker instead." so how can I use the other datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are two datepicker directives with the same name and do check what formation they allow like tag, element or attribute etc.

Comment: I removed the one i want and i get the below warning now : "datepicker is now deprecated. Use uib-datepicker instead."  looks like there is datepicker directive as part of angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Issue found.

Looks like UI Bootstrap still contain 'datepicker' directive which is deprecated and causing this issue .

Now need to see how I can work with both .

Thanks all.

Comment: have you find the solution? please post it for future reference...thanks

Comment: Yes I found a solution. the 720Kb DatePicker provide the option to create the date picker by adding the class 'datepicker' to div element instead of creating <datepicker> element. this why i avoid from the collusion.