# Angular: resolve duplicate directive names in libraries?

Tags: angularjs

I've got two Angular libraries (`angular-bootstrap` and `720kb.datepicker`) which both define a directive named `datepicker` (see also: [Angular DatePicker - Multiple directives > [datepicker, datepicker]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373901/angular-datepicker-multiple-directives-datepicker-datepicker)).

Without modifying the source for either library, how can I rename one or both of the directives so the names don't clash and I can use them?

Comment: A couple people answered in the question you linked to that `720kb.datepicker` lets you apply the directive with `class="datepicker"`... did you try that?